# How to install java library with its source code and javadoc to local repository by using maven

Tags: maven

I have generated binary jar, source code jar and javadoc jar, but the "mvn install" only install the binary java, is there any easy way to also install source code jar and javadoc jar ? Thanks

Comment: how do you generate the source and javadoc jar files? Using the source plugin http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/usage.html and the javadoc plugin http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/  this should be easy. The maven cookbook contains an example as well: http://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/cookbook/attach-source-javadoc-artifacts.html

Comment: I have generated javadoc and source code jar, what I want it is to install it (copy it local repository )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve it is by using the *performRelease* flag

```
mvn -DperformRelease=true clean install
```

It will add sources and javadocs to the installed artifact